# Ubuntu battery indicator jumping between correct reading and unknown 0%

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery

I am running a new installation of Ubuntu 20.04.2 (kernel 5.8.0-43-generic) on an HP Pavilion X2 (10-J008TU) and the battery percentage indicator is jumping between showing the correct reading and unknown 0% in activities bar (not even power settings show the level in these intervals). This only happens when on battery, when AC is plugged in it shows correctly.

Regardless of the Kernel version the problem is the same on all kernels and distros I have tested so far. Fedora 30 (k:5.6), Mint 19 (k:4.15), Manjaro 18 (k:4.14), Ubuntu 18 and 20 (k:5.4, 5.6, 5.11), bionicpup 8 (k:4.9), pop-os 20 (k:5.11)

I have recorded the frequency of the change:

```
xx:51 working
xx:53 unknown (defaults to 0%)
xx:58 working
xx:00 unknown (defaults to 0%)
xx:05 working
xx:07 unknown (defaults to 0%)
xx:11 working
```

Some things I must point out: I had to lock the kernel version to 5.8.0 because of the sound drivers not working in later release

upower -i /org/freedesktop/Upower/devices/battery_BAT0 outputs the following:

```
  native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Thu 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET (1629044245 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    battery-level:       unknown
    icon-name:          '(null)'
```

I hope to hear some creative answers

Comment: I would suggest upgrading your system asap; as a fully-updated Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system will report itself as 20.04.3 (not .2) and not be using the EOL 5.8 kernel, but using either of the GA 5.4 or HWE 5.11 kernel.  You've said you had to *lock* on an EOL/unsupported kernel??  Given that kernel is no longer *patched* nor *supported*, I'd suggest returning to using the GA kernel support that is supported & *patched*.

Comment: As far as I have tested the only compatible kernels with sound are 5.6 and 5.8. I am aware of the risk. I am also looking for a way to fix sound, but this question is specifically about the battery. This battery problem is the same on all kernels I tested. It is something with the battery not reporting the charge level often enough when not on AC power. I would be happy enough if there is a way to make the battery report the last known charge level until it gets a new reading.